# DirectoryServices.AccountManagement UserPrincipal - The old password still works for 5 mins after change or reset the password

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, sharepoint-2010, forms-authentication, userprincipal

The password reset works fine and the user can log in with their new password, but their old password still works. My old password gets expire after 5 mins.
The user is added in the Password Policy group. I tried one tried to stop validating the old password by calling the set password method twice. But as I have set minimum password age 1 day. This trick does not work.

```
       PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
       UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName);
        AdUser adUser = new AdUser();

        if (user != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(randomPassword))
        {
            user.SetPassword(randomPassword);                  

        }

bool status = SPClaimsUtility.AuthenticateFormsUser(Context.Request.UrlReferrer, txtUserName.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim());
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have multiple domain controllers? It could be that it gets changed on one but until the others are synced that the old password would still get successfully verified by the other controllers.

Comment: No I only have one domain controller.